# Links between containers are not working in my Rancher 1.6.21 stack

Tags: docker, dns, rancher

I am using **Rancher 1.6.21** (env: default Cattle) with **Docker 18.06.1-ce** and my problem is that in the same stack the **links** are not working so services cannot communicate.

I tried installing a Docker ***Registry*** stack from the *Rancher Catalog* and I am getting errors in the containers logs because hosts are not accessible, like 'db'. The links are present in the configuration, in the containers shell pinging a service by name (link name or container name) results in **no host found** but by IP it works. In the containers hosts file there is no entry for the respective links.

I also tried a couple of things like creating another stack with a simple mysql db container and a openjdk springboot hello-world app container and I'm having the same issue, and changing the **network type** from ***managed*** to ***bridged*** but this has the same effect. Strangely, the same configuration works on a different server with same specs (other client).

Any ideas on why this can happen? I am presuming there is something wrong in Rancher's configuration but cannot identify what.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
After some more documentation I found that because we are using CATTLE orchestration in rancher all networking management is done by their services (a few containers, ipsec, cni-driver, metadata and network-manager) so I thought there might be the problem but after recreating the setup I still have the same issue, another weird thing is that creating a simple stack with 2 basic ubuntu containers and "linking" them they can see each other by their dns (network, no hosts entry) name.

```
    db:
      image: mysql:5.7.10
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: portus
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${ROOTPASSWORD}
        MYSQL_USER: portus
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DBPASSWORD}
      tty: true
      stdin_open: true
      volumes:
      - ${DIR}/db:/var/lib/mysql
      labels:
        registry.portus.db: 1
    sslproxy:
      image: nginx:1.9.9
      tty: true
      stdin_open: true
      links:
      - portus:portus
      volumes:
      - ${DIR}/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - ${DIR}/proxy:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
      labels:
        io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:container_label_soft: registry.portus.db=1
    registry:
      image: registry:2.3.1
      environment:
        REGISTRY_LOG_LEVEL: warn
        REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED: true
        REGISTRY_AUTH: token
        REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_REALM: https://${DOMAIN}:${PPORT}/v2/token
        REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_SERVICE: ${DOMAIN}:${RPORT}
        REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_ISSUER: ${DOMAIN}
        REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_ROOTCERTBUNDLE: /certs/registry.crt
        REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE: /certs/registry.crt
        REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY: /certs/registry.key
        REGISTRY_HTTP_SECRET: httpsecret
        REGISTRY_NOTIFICATIONS_ENDPOINTS: >
          - name: portus
            url: http://portus:3000/v2/webhooks/events
            timeout: 500
            threshold: 5
            backoff: 1
      tty: true
      stdin_open: true
      links:
      - portus:portus
      volumes:
      - ${DIR}/certs:/certs
      - ${DIR}/data:/var/lib/registry
    lb:
      image: rancher/load-balancer-service
      tty: true
      stdin_open: true
      ports:
      - ${RPORT}:5000/tcp
      - ${PPORT}:443/tcp
      labels:
        io.rancher.loadbalancer.target.sslproxy: ${PPORT}=443
        io.rancher.loadbalancer.target.registry: ${RPORT}=5000
        io.rancher.scheduler.global: 'true'
        io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:not_host_label: lb=0
        io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:not_host_label: registry.enabled=false
      links:
      - registry:registry
      - sslproxy:sslproxy
    portus:
      image: sshipway/portus:2.0.5
      environment: 
        PORTUS_MACHINE_FQDN: ${DOMAIN}
        PORTUS_PRODUCTION_HOST: db
        PORTUS_PRODUCTION_DATABASE: portus
        PORTUS_PRODUCTION_USERNAME: portus
        PORTUS_PRODUCTION_PASSWORD: ${DBPASSWORD}
        PORTUS_GRAVATAR_ENABLED: true
        PORTUS_KEY_PATH: /certs/registry.key
        PORTUS_PASSWORD: ${DBPASSWORD}
        PORTUS_SECRET_KEY_BASE: ${ROOTPASSWORD}
        PORTUS_CHECK_SSL_USAGE_ENABLED: true
        PORTUS_SMTP_ENABLED: false
        PORTUS_LDAP_ENABLED: ${LDAP}
        PORTUS_LDAP_HOSTNAME: ${LDAPHOST}
        PORTUS_LDAP_PORT: ${LDAPPORT}
        PORTUS_LDAP_METHOD: ${LDAPTLS}
        PORTUS_LDAP_BASE: ${LDAPBASE}
        PORTUS_LDAP_UID: cn
        PORTUS_LDAP_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED: ${LDAPBIND}
        PORTUS_LDAP_AUTHENTICATION_BIND_DN: ${LDAPBINDDN}
        PORTUS_LDAP_AUTHENTICATION_PASSWORD: ${LDAPBINDPASS}
        PORTUS_LDAP_GUESS_EMAIL_ENABLED: true
        PORTUS_LDAP_GUESS_EMAIL_ATTR: mail
        PORTUS_PORT: ${PPORT}
        REGISTRY_SSL_ENABLED: true
        REGISTRY_HOSTNAME: ${DOMAIN}
        REGISTRY_PORT: ${RPORT}
        REGISTRY_NAME: Registry
      tty: true
      stdin_open: true
      volumes:
      - ${DIR}/certs:/certs
      - ${DIR}/proxy:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      links:
      - db:db
      labels:
        io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
        io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:container_label_soft: registry.portus.db=1
        registry.portus.app: 1
```

Comment: I thought links were obsolete and not to be used? (replaced by networks)

Comment: can you add more information like dockerfile, docker run, docker-compose file? Because without seeing how you are running docker container. It's difficult to understand and answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for the support, @VonC: yes, the links are absolete but still working, for some reason in Rancher 1.6 they are still being this approach. Rancher 1.6 also has a custom network defined as *managed* but even with this (using network approach) I have the same issue.@Mani: Rancher uses docker-compose and services are wrapped in a custom deliverable package in their Catalog system so I am just clicking install on a Catalog item "Docker Registry" and it deploys the stuff as I did for the other instance of Rancher where it works.

Comment: Any link to docker-compose file like their github page/official website/documentation to view docker-compose file?

Comment: Hey Mani, thank your first, I could not find the rancher registry repo on github even though they have most of the project in github but I can paste the docker-compose.yml to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Links are deprecated in latest version of docker and you can use docker networks as a successor of links. Information from official documentation of docker

```
 Warning: The --link flag is a legacy feature of Docker. It may eventually be 
 removed. Unless you absolutely need to continue using it, we recommend that you use 
 user-defined networks to facilitate communication between two containers instead of 
 using --link. One feature that user-defined networks do not support that you can do 
 with --link is sharing environmental variables between containers. However, you can 
 use other mechanisms such as volumes to share environment variables between 
 containers in a more controlled way.
```

Ref: https://docs.docker.com/network/links/

You can use alteration of --links like user-defined bridge network or default bridge network.

Ref : https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/##differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge

I also tried to change the network type from managed to bridged but this has the same effect. Strangely, the same configuration works on a different server (other client).

Answer for above question:

Because your other client may be using older version of docker or docker-compose V2(or less than) where links are available.

Comment: Thank you @Prem for your answer, I know links are deprecated but they still work even in *Docker 18* (the one I am using) as legacy. *Rancher 1.6* still uses the --links approach but also has a custom network defined (**managed**), I tried both strategies and the services cannot see each other by name *only* by IP. And yes, Rancher uses docker-compose V2.